# Con Python y Selenium: Cómo hacer clic en un botón que está anidado en un shadow-root(open)

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

Estoy intentando hacer web scraping en la siguiente página web:
https://datos.movilidadbogota.gov.co/datasets/movilidadbogota::actor-vial/explore
Mi intención es poder descargar el archivo csv a mi equipo. ¿Alguien con experiencia que me pueda ayudar?

He intentado varias opciones:
Opción1:

```
# Defino función para acceder a shadow_root
def expand_shadow_element(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root

# Navego en la página web
driver.get('https://datos.movilidadbogota.gov.co/datasets/movilidadbogota::actor-vial/about')
time.sleep(7)

download = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html[1]/body[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/button[1]')
download.click()
time.sleep(5)

root1 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "hub-download-card")
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
time.sleep(5)

root2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'hub-download-notice')
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)
time.sleep(5)

root3 = shadow_root2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'calcite-notice')
shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)
time.sleep(5)

csv_download = shadow_root3.find_element(By.NAME, "link")
csv_download.click()
```

El error que arroja es que el elemento no es interactuable. No logro ver dónde esta el recurso para ser descargado

Opción 2:

```
# Defino función para acceder a shadow_root
def expand_shadow_element(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root

# Navego en la página web
driver.get('https://datos.movilidadbogota.gov.co/datasets/movilidadbogota::actor-vial/about')
time.sleep(7)

download = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html[1]/body[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/button[1]')
download.click()
time.sleep(5)

root1 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "hub-download-card")
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
time.sleep(5)

root2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'calcite-button')
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)
time.sleep(5)

csv_download = shadow_root2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button-padding.content--slotted.icon-start-empty.icon-end-empty")
csv_download.click()
```

El error que me arroja acá es: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (-207, 382)

Comment: Hola estuve validando si tu pagina tenia un iframe y no tiene, podrias probar con diferentes xpath como //button[@class='btn btn-default hidden-xs'] y realizar click.